# How to Find the name of the last opened workbook

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2013, you just do it by going to File > open > Recent Workbooks > choose the first in the list.

But can this be done by code ?
Seems easy enough to do, but i didn't find any clue, here or on the net.

note, i think i need the name + full path of the file , and then a simple `workbooks.open Filename`, will do.

Also note, no workbooks are opened at this time, and `thisworkbook.name` is not elligible (or it will loop infinitely to open himself).

i was thinking of something like

```
Dim a as Long
Dim i as Long
Dim Str as String
a= Application.OpenworkbooksHistory.items.count
For i=1 to a
    str = Application.OpenworkbooksHistory.items (i)
    if str<>thisworkbook.path & "\" & thisworkbook.name then
        workbooks.open str
        exit sub
    end if
next i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find a collection of recent files in `Application.RecentFiles`

To open the last one just use `Workbooks.open Application.REcentFiles(1)`

Or you could loop through them if you want something more fancy:

```
For each rfile in application.recentfiles
    if instr(1, rfile.name, "poop") > 0 then
        Workbooks.open rfile.name 
    end if
next
```

Comment: excellent! thats excactly it. You forgot a `.name` on the 2nd line of your answer.